# In-App Coins purchased through web browser

Tags: in-app-purchase, game-center

I am working to develop an iOS mobile app version of an online game that uses in-game coins to enhance game play.  Ideally, I would like to sell these coins through both IAP and through the user's account on the web version of the game.  I am having a difficult time parsing together whether or not this is allowed by Apple and am wondering if anyone has similar experience.

According to Apple's terms:

11.2: Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content,
functionality, or services in an app will be rejected

But also:

11.14 Apps can read or play approved content (specifically magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, and video) that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the app, as long as there is no button or external link in the app to purchase the approved content. Apple will not receive any portion of the revenues for approved content that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the app.  **[This last is from an earlier version of the rules, but it still seems to be the case -- I can purchase a subscription to Pandora on the web or through IAP, right?]**

I know I can't put a link to the web version in the App, and I can't advertise within the app that they can purchase coins online, but is it possible to sync the two accounts across platforms?  Will Apple allow this, or do we need to re-evaluate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The current top-grossing game, Candy Crush Saga, appears to do this, so that seems to be a good precedent.  It can be synced with the Facebook version of the game where items can also be purchased.